# Public Function Space in SSRS

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need the following custom code to embed inside my report.

Public function Space (ByVal rowleft as Decimal , x as Decimal,curTblH as Decimal) As String
    Dim rowleft As Decimal
    If curTblH <= 8.8 cm Then
    rowleft = TblH - curTblH
    x = rowleft/0.8
Return x

What I am trying to do is: if the current table height(curTblH) is lesser than 8.8cm, Calculate how much is left(rowleft), then divide it by 0.8 cm(x), then add (x)number of row more.

And can I get the number of row(x th) in int value?

Comment: Can you summarize what you're trying to do with this code?  Are you hoping to fill all of the empty space on the report page with extra rows or something?

Comment: @molleyc yes, I am trying to fill up the tablix with empty rows. But I only want to do it in report level.  What I am thinking is I would get the number of rows needed to fill up by calculating in embedded custom code. P.S currently I am having groupings inside the tablix, and I have calculated rows in it(subtotal and grandtotal),making it hard for me to have same number of rows displaying per page and adding the blank rows to fill up the tablix.[link]http://tinypic.com/r/zxqtdy/9